# Window close call back url with java script?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function fnUnloadHandler() {

      window.open("http://www.google.com/);
}
</script>
<body onunload="fnUnloadHandler()">

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this code not working. This code used for window close the action on new window open the particular url.

Comment: `language` attribute is no more required

Comment: Using `window.open()` from outside a click handler is typically blocked.

Comment: I think  you are missing end quote. `window.open("http://www.google.com/");`

Comment: I will correct the quote if not working.

Comment: @Siva is it typing mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You can't trigger a new window from a window close event, spammers would love to use that ability to trap people on their sites.

Answer (score 1):

The `open()` method opens a new browser window.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

and you are missing `"`
  `window.open("http://www.google.com/");`

Comment: So that will redirect to another page for 5ms before the window is closed? I don't think that will help much :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are `missing ending of double quote (")`, for opening a new browser window, if you will use following, it should work:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/");
```

instead of

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/);
```

Note: I have tested it on `Google Chrome` browser.